# How can I avoid properties being reset at design-time in tightly bound user controls?

Tags: c#, architecture, user-controls, design-time

I have UserControl 'A' with a label, and this property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the text of the control
    /// </summary>
    [
        Browsable(true),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
        Category("Appearance")
    ]
    public override string Text {
        get {
            return uxLabel.Text;
        }
        set {
            uxLabel.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

I then have UserControl 'B' which has UserControl 'A' on it, and I set the Text Property to "My Example Label" in the designer. Then, I have my MainForm, which has UserControl 'B' on it.

Each time I do a build or run, the Text property of UserControl 'A' is reset to its default value. I suppose this is because since I am doing a rebuild, it rebuilds both UserControl 'A' and 'B', thus causing the problem.

How can I go about a better approach to design pattern to avoid this type of behavior when working with tightly bound controls and forms in a application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Try this:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public override string Text
{
     get { return uxLabel.Text; }
     set { uxLabel.Text = value; }
}
```