# Properties being reset by designer when compiled

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

Anybody have any ideas how to stop properties being reset on custom user control when it is used?

Similar to question: [How can I avoid properties being reset at design-time in tightly bound user controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056080/how-can-i-avoid-properties-being-reset-at-design-time-in-tightly-bound-user-cont)

I have tried the solution in the linked question, but they keep on getting reset.

Example property below: Note i have tried to use a simple property but they keep on getting reset to false every time its the containing form is compiled.

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Description("Appearance")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public bool ImportFilenameShown
{
    get { return txtImportFile.Visible; }
    set
    {
        txtImportFile.Visible = value;
        lblImportFile.Visible = value;
        btnImportMappings.Visible = value;
        btnImportFileBrowse.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

Any help would be good. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: The return value of `.Visible` is complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of `txtImportFile`'s parents are hidden, `txtImportFile.Visible` will always return false.

Therefore, the designer will serialize the wrong value.

Instead, you should store the value in a separate backing field

Comment: I'm sure i tried adding a field, perhaps i didn't set something correctly. Anyway its working correctly now. Cheers.