# C# .NET UserControl Retain Child Control Properties on Cut-And-Paste

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, parent-child

so I managed to build my own simple user control. Basically it is a custom Button containing a child Label control on top of it. The button works as how it should be during runtime.

However during design time I got an issue whenever I cut-and-paste that button (let's say I want to move it from Panel1 to Panel2 by cut-and-paste).

The button itself retains its properties such as background color, etc, but the child Label inside it is reinitialized everytime we paste it, so the text and color inside that label changed back to its default value.
The value of the labels text is set by "Text" property which overrides Text property of the UserControl such as follows :

```
private String _text = "Button";
    [Browsable(true), Description("Sets the text displayed on the button"), Category("Display Settings")]
    public override String Text {
        get => _text;
        set {
            _text = value;
            lb_Text.Text = _text;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to retain child control properties during cut-and-paste in the Designer view?

Below is the code generated for InitializeComponent() section of the UserControl, which will be called whenever it is added to a form. Details aside, I acknowledged that default text and color values is re-initialized there, so I'm not sure how we replace those during cut-and-paste.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lb_Text = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // lb_Text
        // 
        this.lb_Text.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))));
        this.lb_Text.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.lb_Text.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.lb_Text.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.lb_Text.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.lb_Text.Name = "lb_Text";
        this.lb_Text.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
        this.lb_Text.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lb_Text.Text = "Button";
        this.lb_Text.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // MomentaryButton
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackgroundImage = global::HMIControls.Properties.Resources.Button_Normal;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.Controls.Add(this.lb_Text);
        this.Name = "MomentaryButton";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

Comment: Nevermind... I found the answer here :
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054298/2778340](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054298/2778340)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid properties being reset at design-time in tightly bound user controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056080/how-can-i-avoid-properties-being-reset-at-design-time-in-tightly-bound-user-cont)